# How to write an project existing command injection

Tags: java, apache, struts2, struts

I want to write a web project an existing command injection. This is for test-case of my web application scanner. I must write in Struts Freamwork because I should test for this.

I already write some of code in jsp but I don't use the framework. I developed the code with only java. Is struts have a function for `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` ?

```
<s:form method="GET" action ='cmd.jsp' escapeHtml='false' >
<s:textfield name='addr' />
<s:submit value='Submit!' />
</s:form>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%
   String addr = request.getParameter("addr");
   String output = "";
    if(addr != null) {
      String s = null;
      try {
         Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(addr);
```

But this code can't use to Struts MVC structure. Is struts framework have a function for `getRutime.exec()`? Or Do you have any other advice to write a vulnerable application?

Comment: Do you mean like this: https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/OS_Command_Injection_Defense_Cheat_Sheet.md

Comment: Google is your friend: https://blog.sqreen.com/in-code-we-struts/

Comment: Is the PHP tag relevant here?

Comment: Yes Jason I mean like this https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/OS_Command_Injection_Defense_Cheat_Sheet.md but in Struts Freamwork

Comment: "Does Struts have a function for `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`?' Yes, `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`. The question doesn't make any sense as asked: the only way command injection works is if your app takes user input and runs external commands without checking that input.